# In C# Windows Forms, does setting a form's CancelButton property to a button automatically close the form on the button click event?

Tags: c#, winforms, cancel-button

Or by setting the CancelButton property of the form, we just ensure that the button gets enabled on pressing Esc key on the form, but the click event needs to be handled by writing a separate event handler?

Comment: This would have been rather easy to test out for yourself, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

> In C# Windows Forms, does setting a form's CancelButton property to a button automatically close the form on the button click event?

Yes, because doing so sets the [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx) property of that button to `DialogResult.Cancel`. As the documentation for that property states:

> If the DialogResult for this property is set to anything other than `None`, and if the parent form was displayed through the ShowDialog method, clicking the button closes the parent form without your having to hook up any events. The form's DialogResult property is then set to the DialogResult of the button when the button is clicked.

Do note that important caveat: *"if the parent form was displayed through the [ShowDialog method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx)"*. The only way your form will automatically close is if you displayed it using `frm.ShowDialog()`. If you used the [`Show` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx), it won't automatically close. You need to write code to manage that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the form is a dialog. Test it yourself